# jquery find element next to another

Tags: jquery

Hi I have the following html:

```
<p>  
    <input type="text" name="field1"/> <input type="hidden" name="fieldh1"/>  
    <button type="button" class="sendInfo">Send</button>  
</p>  
<p>  
    <input type="text" name="field2" /> <input type="hidden" name="fieldh2"/>  
    <button type="button" class="sendInfo">Send</button>  
</p>
```

What I want is that when user clicks the button, I need to send using ajax the contents of the field field.

This is what i'm trying to do with no success.

```
$(function() {
        $('button.sendInfo').live('click', function() {
            var id = $(this).parent().next('[type=text]').val();
            alert(id);
        });
    });
```

I plan to set what the user types in textbox to the hidden field, and the value received from the ajax call to normal textbox. But the problem is that i can´t even get the value of the textbox that is in the same line as the button the user clicks.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
$(this).siblings('input:text').val();
```

Or change `next` to `find`:

```
$(this).parent().find('[type=text]').val();
```

as `next` only searches the *immediate following sibling*.

Comment: YES! 
This works fine:
$(this).parent().find('[type=text]').val();

Thanks for helping man

Answer (score 2):

I can use [`jQuery.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that "next()" is going to the next sibling of the parent -- and the parent is the `<p>` tag, so the sibling, if it exists, is the following `<p>` tag.

You want `$(this).parent().children('[type=text]').val()` or `$(this).parent().find('[type=text]')`

Answer (score 0):

Can you select your textbox using id ?

```
$(function() { 
   $('button.sendInfo').live('click', function() {
      //what about this:
      var id = $('#textBoxID').val();
      alert(id); 
       //or this
      var id2 = $('+ input', this).val(); 
      alert(id2);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: No because i have many textboxes and i dont want to set handlers for them all individually. I need to identify the textbox right before the pressed button